Creating a VSCode Dev Container image that doesn't require an internet connection
I am working on an academic artifact, where fully offline availability is desirable (and internet access is disabled by default).
I've created a Docker image with my required tooling, but attempting to start a dev container with it while not connected to the internet fails as it attempts to install the VSCode dev server in the container.
Can I create my Docker image (or provide any other dependencies with my artifact) such that internet access is not required?
Things I have attempted:

Installing the VSCode dev server into my image with:
RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh


Committing and exporting the container created by VSCode when it is connected to the internet


Oops, just realised that that's an unofficial VSCode server
